# date and time from unknown format

Tags: xml, datetime

I have some xml files with this lines.

```
<BirthDate>2437092.6250000</BirthDate>
<BirthDate>2437556.3243056</BirthDate>
<BirthDate>2438091.6736111</BirthDate>
<BirthDate>2440862.5208333</BirthDate>
```

It should be date and time,  made with an astrology application (which is broken).

How can I get the real meaning of this data, i.e. date and time, without running the application ?

Comment: Do you know what date/time that the above value is meant to correspond with? Do you have more than a *single* example? It's very difficult to deduce a mapping when we only have one example and don't even have it's equivalent from the other side of the mapping.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I don't know the corresponding date/time values, this is just my problem, because I need to know that. But I have many examples from other files, and I upgraded the question above.

Comment: Usually, datetime values are stored as an integral number of seconds or days since some epoch value (such as 01/01/0001, 01/01/1900 or 01/01/1970) with any fractional part representing the smaller units not covered by the integral part. Unfortunately, the values you're showing look to be far too large to be a count of days since some epoch (2437092 days after 01/01/0001 puts us into the 67th century) and far too small to be a counts of seconds (unless you expect all of the values to be within a month of the epoch - there are 2592000 seconds in a 30 day month)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks a lot for your efforts. I will see what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would *appear* to be [Julian Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) (JD) - which are commonly used in astronomy and astrology.

Using any of the various Julian Day converters [you can find online](https://www.google.com/#q=julian+date+converter), the values you provided would appear to be as follows:

```
2437092.6250000  =  1960-06-07T03:00:00Z
2437556.3243056  =  1961-09-13T19:47:00Z
2438091.6736111  =  1963-03-03T04:10:00Z
2440862.5208333  =  1970-10-03T00:30:00Z
```

Note that it is more than just a simple matter of days since an epoch, as you also have to take into account the Julian to Gregorian calendar changeover, and that they're based on noon instead of midnight.

Also note that the values are intended to be interpreted in [Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_time).  To correlate that to an individual's localized idea of their birth date, you'll need to also know the time zone of their birth location.

This makes sense in an astrology application, but most other types of applications don't record birth dates with such precision.  For a more common approach, see [Handling Birthdays and Other Anniversaries](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/09/handling-birthdays-and-other-anniversaries/).

Comment: Looks reasonable. Of course, since the OP doesn't have knowledge of even a single mapping, there's no way to verify that those are the correct outputs. But +1.